# convert Bit Array{2} to Array{Bool,1} in julia

Tags: julia

So, as the title explains:
Is there a way to convert a `BitArray{2}` type array to a `Array{Bool,1}:` type array?

PD: the core of the problem is that I am trying to evaluate an `Array{float64,2}` with a `BitArray{2}` and I keep getting the following error:
`ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 20×1 Array{Float64,2} at index [Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(20)), Base.LogicalIndex(Bool[0; 0; … ; 0; 0]), Base.Slice(Base.OneTo(1))]`

Thanks in advance!

@Mason
EDIT:

So, I have been trying to isolate the outliers present in an `array{Float64,2}`. I found this [two functions](https://github.com/mrxiaohe/RobustStats.jl/blob/master/src/functions.jl) online and edited them to allow `Array{float64,2}` arrays as inputs.

```
function idealf(x::Array{Float64,2})
    y       = sort(x,dims=1);
    n       = length(x);
    j       = floor(Int64, n/4+5/12) # 25%ile is in [y[j], y[j+1]]
    k       = n-j+1        # 75%ile is in [y[k],y[k-1]]
    g       = n/4+5/12 - j   # weighting for the two data surrounding quartiles.
    (1-g).*y[j]+g.*y[j+1], (1-g).*y[k]+g.*y[k-1]
end

function outbox(x::Array{Float64,2}; mbox::Bool=false, gval::Real=NaN, method::Bool=true)
    n = length(x);
    lower_quartile, upper_quartile = idealf(x)
    IQR = upper_quartile-lower_quartile
    cl = cu = 0.0
    if mbox
        if isnan(gval)
            gval=(17.63*n-23.64)/(7.74*n-3.71)
        end
        cl = median(x) - gval*IQR
        cu = median(x) + gval*IQR
    elseif !mbox
        if isnan(gval)
            gval=1.5
        end
        cl = lower_quartile - gval*IQR
        cu = upper_quartile + gval*IQR
    end
    flag = (x.<cl) .| (x.>cu)
    flag=collect(flag) # tunring my BitArray{2} to a Array{float64,2}
    vec = collect(1:n);
    outid  = vec[flag,:] # TROUBLE HERE
    keepid = vec[.!flag] # TROUBLE HERE
    outval = x[flag]
 
    nout = length(outid)
    if method && !mbox
        METHOD = "Outlier detection method using \nthe ideal-fourths based boxplot rule\n"
    elseif method && mbox
        METHOD = "Outlier detection method using \nthe ideal-fourths based boxplot rule\n(using the modification suggested by Carling (2000))\n"
    else
        METHOD = nothing
    end
    return outid, keepid, outval, nout;
end

a=rand(20,1)*10; a[10]=1000.0;a[2]=2000.0;
outbox(a)
```

And I am having a problem to evaluate on lines: `outid  = vec[flag,:]` and `vec[.!flag]`. As of today, I couldn't find a solution to go beyond this line of the function. Do you have any idea on how can I evaluate this vector `vec` en the array `flag`?

I am trying to run it with an array:

```
a=rand(20,1)*10;# 20 random numbers in (0,1]
a[10]=1000.0    # input an outlier on index 10...
```

Comment: Please try to edit this to make a minimal working example rather than dump your entire production code. In that way the questions and its answers can be useful for other people too. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Ok, so I have edited the chunk of code so it can be pasted into a terminal (including the toy data to run it) and it will reproduce the error. No need for any package (just open Julia in terminal and paste this). hope this is enough
! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can use `collect` to turn a `BitArray` into an `Array`, and `vec` to turn a matrix into a vector:

```
julia> BA = BitArray(rand(Bool, 3, 3))
3×3 BitArray{2}:
 0  1  0
 1  0  1
 1  0  0

julia> collect(BA)
3×3 Array{Bool,2}:
 0  1  0
 1  0  1
 1  0  0

julia> (vec ∘ collect)(BA)
9-element Array{Bool,1}:
 0
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 1
 0
```

Looking at your "PD" though, I suspect this won't solve your underlying issue, but you haven't provided enough information for me to help with that.

---

Edit in response to OP's edit:

The problem is that you're trying to logically index a `Vector` with a `BitMatrix` of size `(20, 1)`. Julia will not automatically treat single column matrices as vectors, unlike Matlab. There are good reasons for this, but I get that it can be surprising.

Instead of using `collect` on your `BitMatrix`, you should instead use `dropdims(flag, dims=2)` to turn `flag` into a `BitVector` which is valid for logical indexing.

Here's your original code but with the suggested fix:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC julia
function idealf(x::Array{Float64,2})
    y       = sort(x,dims=1);
    n       = length(x);
    j       = floor(Int64, n/4+5/12) # 25%ile is in [y[j], y[j+1]]
    k       = n-j+1        # 75%ile is in [y[k],y[k-1]]
    g       = n/4+5/12 - j   # weighting for the two data surrounding quartiles.
    (1-g).*y[j]+g.*y[j+1], (1-g).*y[k]+g.*y[k-1]
end

function outbox(x::Array{Float64,2}; mbox::Bool=false, gval::Real=NaN, method::Bool=true)
    n = length(x);
    lower_quartile, upper_quartile = idealf(x)
    IQR = upper_quartile-lower_quartile
    cl = cu = 0.0
    if mbox
        if isnan(gval)
            gval=(17.63*n-23.64)/(7.74*n-3.71)
        end
        cl = median(x) - gval*IQR
        cu = median(x) + gval*IQR
    elseif !mbox
        if isnan(gval)
            gval=1.5
        end
        cl = lower_quartile - gval*IQR
        cu = upper_quartile + gval*IQR
    end
    flag = dropdims((x.<cl) .| (x.>cu), dims=2) 
    vec = collect(1:n)
    
    outid  = vec[flag]
    keepid = vec[.!flag]
    outval = x[flag]
 
    nout = length(outid)
    if method && !mbox
        METHOD = "Outlier detection method using \nthe ideal-fourths based boxplot rule\n"
    elseif method && mbox
        METHOD = "Outlier detection method using \nthe ideal-fourths based boxplot rule\n(using the modification suggested by Carling (2000))\n"
    else
        METHOD = nothing
    end
    return outid, keepid, outval, nout;
end

a=rand(20,1)*10; a[10]=1000.0;a[2]=2000.0;
outbox(a)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: ([2, 10], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [2000.0, 1000.0], 2)
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer. Please, see that I have edited the post to give more information on my problem!

Comment: Nice!. Just what I needed. Thaks a Lot!